# Exposing WCF class reference method client side

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, wcf-client, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a WCF Service. I add reference of a DLL in the WCF service.Now ddl has a class, i'm able to get access of the class at WCF client side by using the serviceknowntypeattribute but not the functions inside the class.Any solution?

Comment: are you sharing an assembly between client and server? or just using a service reference?

Comment: I tried sharing the assembly as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that You are using autogenerated code (by Add Service Reference in Visual Studio).
This creates a stub for your class (only a container) but it is not actually your class.
To use your actual class in client code you must reference it in client project and in service reference advanced options make sure you have 'use types from referenced assemblies' checked.